# How can I not get a joke in my dream?

Tags: dreams

## The Dream

Today I had a dream. I was in class where I and my classmate were chosen to be examined. Once seated in front of the teacher we got our questions. She accidentally saw mine and made a funny remark about it. I did not get it at first and so I just smiled in a general way. Since in real life she is used to me getting her jokes she immediately explained it to me. Only then did I understand it and had a good laugh.

## The Question

How can I not get a joke made de facto by myself (even though on behalf of someone else) in a dream?

Comment: Welcome to this stack. Very interesting! However, we do expect questions to be based on limited initial research here (e.g., an article clarifying this is a more common phenomenon, not an isolated case you encounter). To help with this, I suggest generalizing it, i.e., do you think there is a real reason to focus specifically on 'not getting jokes'? It makes a nice example, but try to phrase it as a general question.

Comment: One possibility: did you remember the actual joke, or only the notion there was a joke you did not get? Thinking back on similar dreams I had, I believe it is typically the 'feeling' associated with the experience you recall and not concrete things. Without trying to remember the concrete, it 'feels' like there was an actual joke.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Thank you for the warm welcome! Now that I think about it, in order to understand the joke I had to recall a specific situation in the past (which my classmate had reminded me of). Shall I rephrase this question or delete it and ask a new one?

Comment: @StevenJeuris I am pretty sure I knew what the joke was about immediately after waking up, but I don't remember it now precisely. But maybe it was just a feeling, I am not 100% sure.

Comment: you can rephrase this question as if you asked it the first time around with the additional guidance I gave you in an edit.

Comment: This question itself is pretty hilarious. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

It maybe the joke was the dream-equivalent of a MacGuffin, a fuzzy, unimportant placeholder that wasn’t materialized into actual language, and that the point of the scene was to experience awkwardness, embarrassment, inferiority or exclusion that others had the upper-hand with in-group knowledge unavailable to the subject?

It would fit that what seems real in a dream isn’t necessarily real... that the idea of certainty came from the dream while waking up, but the actual content of that certainty likely never existed.

Comment: No, the joke was not built on me not being able to answer the question. It was targeted at me, but not in the offensive way. I was actually flattered in the way: "hey, you you actually remember this?". Now, whether it was materialized into actual language - I think it was. I can't be 100% sure though.

Comment: I swore someone crashed into the wall in my bedroom. There was no one there and there was no logical source of it. Not even Casper or Slimer. I thought it was very real and woke up, but I’m completely convinced now I dreamt it due to Exploding Head Syndrome (EHS). But you see, the feeling of real, surreal or dream is itself a manifested feeling that can also be dreamt. Furthermore, the brain doesn’t wake up entirely and instantly... some parts are pressing an imaginary snooze button while taking a final exam naked while other parts are woke to the real world and ready for coffee.

Comment: How can we find out whether we really dreamt the thing or whether we just had a certain feeling and later on made up the story to cause that feeling? Sometimes when I wake up I do have certain feeling and recal a fuzzy situation from dream (which later on somehow gets more and more detailed). Other times, including this one, I actually recall the situation more concretely with actual people and vivid images of them and the environment.